# Akka-Persistence -Is it ok to use mutable states with akka PersistentActor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

Is it ok to use mutable states with ***akka PersistentActor*** or shall I use `context.become/unbecome` with *receiveCommand()* and not with the *receiveRecover()* as it will wait for the full recovery before the state is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you *can't* use `context.become` and friends within a `PersistentActor` because those affect the `receive` method, which is provided by the `PersistentActor` (and handles some internal messages which are implementation details, so you don't really want to duplicate it).

Being more explicit about the mutable state than `context.become` is a better path.

There is a pattern of wrapping up all the mutable state into a single immutable object (e.g. a Scala `case class`) and deferring the command handling to that object, which could be as simple as something like:

```scala
var state: State = ???

override val receiveCommand: Receive = state.processCommand(_)
```

You can go further and have your `processCommand` method on `State` return, e.g. a `(Seq[Event], () => Try[Unit])`... this is actually fairly close to what projects like Lagom or Typed Persistence are doing.